# Vue3 Vite application deployed into a Flask server not working and giving no error messages

Tags: vue.js, flask, npm, vite

I am learning Vue3 and I am trying to write an application with a Vue frontend and a Flask (python) backend.

The application (available from https://github.com/karthik892/vue3-flask-moviedb-ui) displays a list of movies from the TMDB API.

This application works fine in development (i.e. using `npm run dev`) and displays a sample navbar and list of movies returned by the API.

However, when I deploy the app into the static folder of my flask application. I only get a page that shows the sample navbar and nothing else. There are no errors in the console to explain what is going on.

My process for deploying the vue application is as follows:

- run `npm run build`
- copy the files in the `dist` folder to the `static` folder of my Flask application.
- Modify the url's in `index.html` so that the js and css load correctly
- Start the flask server and open the url at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/index.html`

Comment: You cannot use your Flask development server as a production server. You're requesting `127.0.0.1` from your Component which is throwing a `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` exception in your console (Open your developer console).

Comment: To clarify, there are no error messages in the developer console. Also, on the server side I am using the ```flask_cors``` library and on the client (vue) I have specified the ```server.proxy``` property in my ```vite.config.js``` file (but, that shouldn't matter is production because everything is running on the flask server, right?). Also, the network tab in developer tools does not show any request after the js and css file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to change the history mode for my Vue Router. In your `createRouter()` you should have the following property:

```
history: createWebHashHistory()
```

optionally, this will make dealing with relative paths a lot easier

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path != "" and os.path.exists(app.static_folder + '/' + path):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')
```

I suppose that you could move `index.html` into the `templates` folder of your flask app, but that would probably require messing with URL's or your `server.proxy`